# 404 Not Found error when using ajax in Laravel

Tags: ajax, laravel

I've set up a comment board and am using ajax to send what users typed in along with other relevant data using through a route. However, whenever i try to do so, the console sends me a 404 error.

[image]

this is the ajax code

```
if ($('#discussionBoardNewComment').val()) {
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/project/identification/comment/{{$project}}",
    data: {
        comment: $("textarea[name='discussionBoardNewComment']").val(),
    },
}
```

This is the result from my route:list
[image]

Tell me if there is anything else you need

Comment: I don't know if it's relevant, but you aren't passing the csrf `_token` with the ajax request

Comment: @linktoahref that would result in a `TokenMismatchException` instead of `NotFoundHttpException`.

Comment: @IvankaTodorova yeah, correct!

Comment: Assuming you use standard routes, you need to pass the project id in the url. So is `$project` the project id?

Comment: @Sandeesh Hi Sandeesh thx for replying, $project is a Project object with the id located inside. even when i specify $project->id in the url, it still doesn't work

Comment: How are you even showing that error page? You only have a post route to add comments, so opening the link in browser would try to access the get route. And ajax call shouldn't redirect. You need to post your view code with the form along with complete js code.

Answer (score 1):

Obviously this is not your path. Try using [`action()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/helpers#method-action) for generating your url.

```
if ($('#discussionBoardNewComment').val()) {
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "{{action('ProjectsController@comment', ['project' => $project->id])}}",
    data: {
        comment: $("textarea[name='discussionBoardNewComment']").val(),
    },
}
```

Comment: Hi Ivanka, Thanks for replying. When i changed my url to fit yours, i get the error "Action App\Http\Controllers\App\Http\Controllers\ProjectController@comment not defined. "

Comment: Oh, darn, it should be only `action('ProjectsController@comment', ['project' => $project])`. I have updated my answer.